# C++ HDF5 Compilation Error: -lhdf5 not found

Tags: c++, hdf5

I wrote a small program which `#include <H5Cpp.h>` to read dataset from a `.h5` file. If I compile it without any extra flags it reports a lot of undefined references. I heard `-lhdf5` is my best shot.

```
g++ pg.cpp -lhdf5 -o pg.out
```

generates

```
/usr/bin/ld: -lhdf5 not found
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`h5cc -show` gives me this

```
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -I/usr/bin/miniconda3/include -DNDEBUG
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize 
-fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe - 
I/usr/bin/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix- 
map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda- 
prefix -L/usr/bin/miniconda3/lib /usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/libhdf5_hl.a 
/usr/bin/miniconda3/lib/libhdf5.a -L/usr/bin/miniconda3/lib -Wl,-O2 - 
Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,- 
rpath,/usr/bin/miniconda3/lib -L/usr/bin/miniconda3/lib -lrt -lpthread 
-lz -ldl -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/bin/miniconda3/lib
```

What should I do to make g++ recognize `-lhdf5`? If the following info is helpful helping you solve my problem.

- My CPATH doesn't include HDF5 by default so I exported it.
- `/usr/include` and `miniconda3/include` both have HDF5 installed.

Comment: You miss *at least* `-L/usr/bin/miniconda3/lib` can you try with it? Also, the conda-installed HDF5 probably does *not* include the C++ interface. You could try to use the plain C interface for HDF5.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Tried. Same undefined references error as when I use no flags. Do you mean use C flags with g++? Which flags should I use?

Comment: I mean to use the C API in `hdf5.h` instead of `H5Cpp.h`. This is somewhat orthogonal to the linker issue though. What does `which g++` return?

Comment: `/usr/bin/g++`. Under `miniconda3/lib` I can see a bunch of `libhdf5_cpp.*`. Does that mean conda has c++ interface?

Comment: A reddit post hinted me that `h5c++ -show pg.cpp` will show you the command needed to successfully compile. I tried and it compiled silently. Seems I installed static libraries such that `-lhdf5` won't work.

Comment: Yes, you have the C++ interface. I missed the call to h5cc instead of h5c++ of course, good that you could resolve the issue.